# client.user.setActivity found as null? (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to set the activity of my Discord bot as a "game" however the examples I've found online haven't helped at all.

```
client.user.setActivity("what the bot is playing");
```

Does not work at all, it gives me this error stating that I am trying to find something that is null (non-existent... in non programming terms)

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setActivity')
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/DiscordBot/index.js:46:13)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

Comment: Where did you place that code? Like, inside of an event, or just randomly inside of the index.js file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're probably trying to change the bot's status before it's online. Try putting it inside of the ready event instead.

```
client.on("ready", () => {
    client.user.setActivity("what the bot is playing");
});
```

Comment: Very similar to that, you do need to clarify whether the bot is playing or streaming though.